# MySQL: myisamchk recover error after "mysqlhotcopy --noindices" on table whose index file was larger than 2048 bytes

Tags: mysql

I have a program that uses a MySQL database. Backups are done with `mysqlhotcopy --noindices` and restores done with `myisamchk --recover`.

When restore I got an error for the table whose original index file was larger than 2048 bytes:

```
myisamchk: Unknown error 126: '/var/lib/mysql/bak/foo.MYI' doesn't have a correct index definition. You need to recreate it before you can do a repair
```

Here is the minimal example:

```
$ mysql db <<< 'truncate table foo;'
$ ls -l /var/lib/mysql/db/foo.MYI
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql  3072 Jul 21 01:02 /var/lib/mysql/db/foo.MYI
$ mysqlhotcopy --noindices db bak
$ ls -l /var/lib/mysql/bak/foo.MYI
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql  2048 Jul 21 01:02 /var/lib/mysql/bak/foo.MYI
$ myisamchk -r /var/lib/mysql/bak/foo.MYI
myisamchk: Unknown error 126: '/var/lib/mysql/bak/foo.MYI' doesn't have a correct index definition. You need to recreate it before you can do a repair
```

In the documentation I found only this:

```
$ perldoc /usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
    --noindices    Don’t include index files in copy. Only up to the first 2048 bytes are copied;  You can restore the indexes with isamchk -r or myisamchk -r on the backup.
```

Why can't `myisamchk` recover the database?

Using mysql 5.1.73, mysqlhotcopy 1.23, myisamchk-2.7.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .MYI file, then REPAIR the table.

*AND* seriously consider changing to InnoDB (from MyISAM).

Comment: Hi, Rick! Thanks for your help.

I am not an author. The program uses MySQL in its own way. There is no option to use InnoDB or something.

It runs "mysqlhotcopy --noindices" on backup, and "myisamchk --recover" on restore.

I see that myisamchk is unable to recover tables whose index file was larger than 2048 bytes and trying to figure out if this is a software bug.